# maven: apklib "expanding to null"

Tags: android, maven, apk, android-maven-plugin

I'm trying to use an `apklib` in my Maven build. I've pushed it to my local repository with `install:install-file` as usual. Then it gets included in the build with:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.scoreloop</groupId>
        <artifactId>scoreloop-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>apklib</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Running the build now produces the following line:

```
[INFO] [android:generate-sources {execution: default-generate-sources}]
[DEBUG] Expanding: C:\Users\vertti\Documents\My Dropbox\dev-folder\m2\repository\com\scoreloop\scoreloop-ui\2.3.2\scoreloop-ui-2.3.2.apklib into null
[DEBUG] expand complete
```

Well... umm.. thanks, `null` is exactly where I want my apklibs :)

I'm using Maven 2.2.1 and maven-android-plugin 2.9.0-beta-5

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Do you have problems with maven in other projects? Maven has problems is it's repository (the `m2` dir) resides on path with spaces.

Comment: Nope, all has been working just fine so far, I got around 10 dependencies, half of them added manually with the above mentioned `install:install-file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not a real answer but I upgraded to Maven 3 and android-maven-plugin 3.0.3 alpha 11 and the same pom.xml works now.